# histogram axis settings

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have some problems with the histogram. I have to:

1. the axis x is double labeled and I should live only one label for each bar.
2. each bar has to have a different color (red, blue, green, purple).

the code and the result are the following.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
symbolic x coords={$400$,$500$,$600$,$700$},
ymajorgrids=true,
ymin=0,
width=9cm, height=6.5cm
]
\addplot [ybar, bar width=.8cm, fill=blue, draw=black] coordinates
{($400$, 0.044) ($500$, 0.044) ($600$, 0.044) ($700$, 0.100)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why it makes a double label, but you can easily avoid it since you use numbers for xlabels by using `xtick=data` instead of `symbolic x coords`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits of this go to Jake.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,compat=1.12
    ,select row/.style={%
        x filter/.code={\ifnum\coordindex=#1\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi}
        }
    }

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
    400 0.044
    500 0.044
    600 0.044
    700 0.100
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
    xtick={0,...,4},
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{0},
ymajorgrids=true,
ymin=0,
width=9cm, height=6.5cm,
ybar,bar width=.8cm,bar shift=0pt
]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,4}{
    \addplot+[draw=black] table [select row=#1, x expr=#1] {\datatable};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great!! but I receive the following error:
! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.12' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/compat/
anchors'. I am going to ignore this key.

Comment: Set `compat=` to the version of `pgfplots` you are using. Or update your system to get version 1.12.

Comment: How are the bar colors controlled in this example?

Comment: Adding `,fill=red` after `draw=black` in the `\addplot` option did it for me.